# First and last occurence of a symbol (python without regex)

Tags: python, regex, string

I am dealing with a string from 'ACGT' alphabet (a genetic sequence) padded by letters 'N' in the beginning and in the end:

```
NNN...NNACGT...GGCTAANNNN...NNN
```

I would like to find the positions where the actual sequence begins and ends. It could be easily done by using regular expressions, but I would like to have a simpler solution using basic python string operations. Your suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: @JvdV How could I use them to know where the string begins/ends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the remainder (removing padding from left and right) it seems like all you need is:

```
<YourString>.strip('N')
```

If you need to find indices maybe refer to `lstrip` and `rstrip` instead:

```
sStart = len(<YourString>)-len(<YourString>.lstrip('N'))+1
sEnd = len(<YourString>.rstrip('N'))
```

Comment: This doesn't address my problem : I need the position of the string, i.e. the indices where it begins and ends

Comment: I knew that it it must be very simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you wanted to find the 'positions'. The code below will give you the positions where the actual sequence starts and ends in the string.

```
s = 'NNNNAANNNN'

i, j = s.find(next((x for x in s if x != 'N'), None)), s.rfind(next((x for x in reversed(s) if x != 'N'), None))

print(i, j)
print(s[i:j+1])

#Output
4 5
A A
```

Comment: Thanks. Kind of works, but for some reason misses the correct place by a few positions.

Comment: Could it be sensitive to presence of additional Ns inside the string of interest?

Comment: It won't mind any other Ns inside. It doesn't change the original string at all. Merely returns a subset of the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Use strip()

```
    s = "NNNNNACGTGGCTAANNNNNNN"
    s = s.strip('N')
    print(s)
```